# Put a cursor to a beginning of each line

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

Is there any way to put a cursor to a beginning of each line in Sublime Text, given that the beginning of each line is different so it's impossible to do a search by a pattern and then select all the occurrences? I want to do that without any plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to MattDMo's answer could be to `select all` (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>), then `split selection into lines` (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>), then `move to the beginning of the line` (<kbd>home</kbd>) to get the cursors in the proper position and cancel out the selection.

This would avoid the regex search.

Answer (score 1):

Do a regex search for `\n`, then hit `Find All` (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>) to select all the newline characters (the very end of each line). Next, hit <kbd>←</kbd> to remove the selections, which places the cursors at the end of each line. Finally, hit <kbd>Home</kbd> twice to move the cursors to the beginning of each line.